# getProperty from Properties.java file is returning ${browser} instead of null when no value is passed

Tags: java, selenium, properties, properties-file

So, we have this selenium.properties file from where we get the browser details from the below tag.

browser = ${browser}

When we run through maven command, this value get populated based on what we pass in -Dbrowser and its all good. However, when we don't pass in a browser value, instead of returning us null value getProperty is returning "${browser}" as value. How to avoid this?

Tried googling about this but no real info on how to fix this.

Comment: try `${browser:-}`, `${browser:}`, or `${browser-}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, that didn't work :(